# How to close/end a Wire.begin()?

Tags: i2c, esp32

I have an ESP32 cam, and I attached an i2c light sensor to it. I need to read the light level at startup, then I don't need the i2c connection again.
The problem is, the board uses 2 i2c connections I think (for the camera and such). So I use my custom pins for the sensor (15 and 16). It works well, I can read the light just fine, but then the camera fails because (I believe) the Wire.begin(15,16) changes the default pins and the camera gets confused.

So I would like to do something like Wire.end() to forget that I started the Wire.begin(). Any idea on how I can do that?

Here is the relevant code:

```
#define I2C_SDA 16
#define I2C_SCL 15
BH1750 lightMeter (0x23);
TwoWire I2Clightmeter= TwoWire(1);

void setup() 
{
  I2Clightmeter.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
  lightMeter.begin(BH1750::ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE,0x23,&I2Clightmeter);

  delay(1000);
  uint16_t lux = lightMeter.readLightLevel();

//rest of the code
```

Comment: Have you *tried* `Wire.end()`?

Comment: Yes, of course. But there is no such function.

Comment: Looks like that's something Arduino overlooked. It's something we (optionally) implemented in chipKIT...  There is a way though, but it's not too fun.

Comment: This is the esp32 header for wire: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h If there is a way, I'd like to know it, because I can't use the camera without it :/

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this, but since I don't have a BH1750, I just ran the solution #1 from the answer below without anything attached and it does _not_ crash for me. So maybe the bug is not in the wire library but in the lightmeter library (as it may register some interrupts). Try dynamically allocating that one as well.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The program doesn't require a physical board, or even actually using the library. Just starting a  I2Clightmeter.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL); is enough to crash when the camera is initialized. However, I found a solution: moving SDA on pin 14 seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way of doing it that's ESP32 specific. However it means changing how you define your I2C object.

The ESP32 system is set up so that if the TwoWire instance is destructed the I2C bus is released. But you can't do that with the way you normally define the object. So instead you have to use dynamic allocation to control it:

```cpp
TwoWire *I2Clightmeter;

void setup() {
    I2Clightmeter = new TwoWire(1);
    I2Clightmeter->begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
    lightMeter.begin(BH1750::ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE,0x23,I2Clightmeter);
    delay(1000);
    uint16_t lux = lightMeter.readLightLevel();
    delete I2Clightmeter;
    // rest of code
}
```

Another alternative is to keep the TwoWire object in a local scope so that it gets destroyed when you leave that scope - maybe with a special function for it:

```cpp
uint16_t getLux() {
    TwoWire I2Clightmeter(1);
    I2Clightmeter.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
    lightMeter.begin(BH1750::ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE,0x23,&I2Clightmeter);
    delay(1000);
    return lightMeter.readLightLevel();
}

void setup() {
    uint16_t lux = getLux();
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. If I put the delete there, it just boot loops. If I don't put the delete, it gives me the message as it did before: [W][esp32-hal-i2c.c:905] i2c_isr_handler_default(): eject raw=0x2, int=0x200

Comment: Did you try the second option? Localise it?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I don't see how it would work, since most likely once the function is called in c (on the esp32 specific code) it will set something that persists there until the device is rebooted or some other magic thing happens to reset it. Btw, the camera code does NOT use wire() in my program. It is used by the libraries in the backend. The only i2c code in my program is reading the light sensor.

Comment: It's worth trying. Give it a go and report back.

Comment: Another option is just to use the other i2c channel, and maybe other pins too.

Comment: Trying the first channel was one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately, it still crashed.

Comment: I tried the scope version, and, unsurprisingly, it got stuck in a bootloop too...

Comment: Hmm... then I am out of ideas at the moment, sorry. Maybe raise it as an issue on the github repo - it really shouldn't cause it to crash.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I appreciate it. I asked on the esp32.com forum, if I don't get an answer there too I will open an issue on github as well.

Comment: Btw, from looking at the code, deleting the object should release the i2c. Unfortunately, something else is going on :/ TwoWire::~TwoWire()
{
    flush();
    if(i2c) {
        i2cRelease(i2c);
        i2c=NULL;
    }
}

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the idea of destroying the object from. Maybe the problem isn't with the I2C - maybe the problem is with the camera code. I know you probably don't get much control over that though as it's mostly embedded in the core.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. I moved SDA on pin 14, and now it works, for some reason :D I believe it's still a bug with esp-32 cam, but at least I got it to work.